# Will code built with Android's NDK run on ART as it does on Dalvik?

Tags: android, android-ndk

With KitKat, Android now has a substitute for the Dalvik VM: [ART](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html).  Are there any differences in compatibility when running NDK code on ART vs Dalvik?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Nexus 5 and KitKat came out we set one of our QA devices to ART exclusively.  Since then every release of our game has been tested with it and we've found no bugs that are exclusive to ART.  Our game is almost entirely NDK code with Java being used for text rendering, and platform specific SDKs.  (IAP, Achievements, 3rd party SDKs like Flurry etc...)

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  Is there any reason for you to believe that the ART would behave differently than Dalvik?

Comment: No it was mostly defensive testing.  We figured if there was an issue people would blame the app not the alpha feature they enabled on their device and we'd get 1 * ratings from it.